# How to install SharePoint, What is the cost of it, How many users can use it.?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I've basic Question about SharePoint :-

1) How to install SharePoint Foundation free version and what are the functionality.

2) What is the cost of SharePoint Server 2013 and If I purchase is it one time investment or I've to pay some money in future also.

3) How many users can use this server or after purchase the SharePoint Server it will be free for the users which I'll add to access the SharePoint Server or I've to pay money for per user .

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. to install and Configure the SPF 2013, please check this [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262957(v=office.15).aspx) loaded with all resources. or more spefic to SPF check [this](http://www.sharepoint-articles.com/blog/sharepoint-2013-foundation-installation-guide/). Check [this blog](http://florianlaumer.wordpress.com/2013/01/15/sharepoint-2013-standard-vs-enterprise-vs-foundation-feature-comparison-matrix/) for all feature comparison
2. Its depend upon on the your requirement, How many users you have and what zone you want intranet or internet. **For On-Premises**, intranet sites are licensed using a Server/CAL (Client Access License) model. SharePoint Server 2013 is required for each running instance of the software, and CALs are required for each person or device accessing a SharePoint Server. [SharePoint 2013 licensing](http://products.office.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-licensing-overview)
3. it is not free, you have to covered every user under a CAL.

[SharePoint 2013 Licensing Simplified](http://blah.winsmarts.com/2012-12-SharePoint_2013_Licensing_Simplified.aspx)

Comment: Waqas, So If I want to use SharePoint Foundation for Intranet purpose, what I understand is I've to invest only for Hardware and Software (Window server) to setup the farm and I can use it for my company. There is no extra expense or cost like per user licensed / CALs in SharePoint Foundation. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes and No...SPF is free but you have the Windows OS CALs for each user who want to use the SPF. Separate License if you are using SQL Server full version not express.

Answer (score -1):

If you're going to build SharePoint farms then you should use https://autospinstaller.codeplex.com and avoid the MS SharePoint installation wizard. The autoSPInstaller will help you to think how you should install SharePoint with service accounts.

Comment: This does not answer the question as per the StackExchange standards. Please check [answer]. Add details like why your answer is the best solution.